# Outlook glitches out when displaying email signatures after Windows 10 upgrade from 7

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I've recently upgraded a couple of PCs in our company to Windows 10 from Windows 7. These both had Outlook 2013 installed.

After upgrading (and installing the latest graphics drivers) the email signatures that show when composing a new email or replying have glitched. Instead of showing the correct images in the signature, it just shows a random snip of the screen (the image below explains it much better).

[image: Outlook screenshot]]

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Outlook with 2013 and 2016 with the same result. I've also re-installed graphics drivers, and remove and re-added the user's outlook profile. This only occurs when writing an email, and only when the signature is applied. If sent, the emails display fine to the recipient.

I also tried disabling hardware-accelerated graphics, but this caused outlook to display completely wrong, just showing white for most of the window. I had to edit the setting in the registry to get it to change back as I couldn't open the options menu after that.

Our email signatures are deployed with a tool called Exclaimer Signature Manager Outlook Edition, which has worked fine with windows 7 in the past and is working fine with at least one other PC that was upgraded to Windows 10 in the same way.

I've done a bit more testing and the same thing happens in Word if you insert any image, so it's not just outlook but the whole Office suite.

Had anyone seen this before or know anything else I can try?

Comment: I've done a bit more testing and the same thing happens in Word if you insert any image, so it's not just outlook but the whole Office suite.

Comment: Have you tried running Outlook/Word in compatibility mode for Windows 7?  _Right-click > Troubleshoot Compatibility_ or _File properties > Compatibility > Run this program in... Windows 7_.  Beyond that, I'm unsure how to troubleshoot, however, my hunch is it has to do with OS and/or driver issues resulting from upgrading the OS versus clean installing Win10.  **Quick test:** throw in a spare drive, clean install Windows 10 to the spare drive, install Chipset & any other CPU drivers, install all Windows Updates, finally install Office 2013.  If issue is no longer present, it's the upgrade.

Comment: @Perry _Please don't create multiple comments if all text will fit into one comment_ =]  Josh stated it occurs with any photo in Word, and not just with the signature.

Comment: @Perry because we're not a forum. You have some reputation here, didn't you took the time to see how SE works?

Comment: And you shouldn't post answers in comments as well.

Comment: Yes, nice forum!  So when I put it in Answer, someone said this is a comment, I changed it to comment, and then now, this is an answer? Thank you for the reminder from both of you. I'll take care of my replies.

Answer (score 1):

Further testing revealed this error occurs only with the 32-bit version of Office. After upgrading to 64-bit this issue went away. Ideally, there would be a fix for 32-bit versions but for now just going to 64-bit is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the image insert problem with Office 2013 64 bit after an in-place upgrade from Win7Pro to Win10Pro.

Workaround for Word, Excel and Powerpoint:
(i) insert image. Displays random pixels from elsewhere on screen
(ii) cut image.
(iii) paste-special image as windows enhanced metafile

There is a raster graphics rendering issue in Office 2013-64 bit on Win10 I haven't got to the bottom of. Does not seem to happen if the image is pasted as windows enhanced metafile. Note the display is also scrambled if you insert a WMF, it has to be pasted.